# How can you store labels in an array and display them using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a label that I'm using with a form that I created in react. How do I display the values from my array and map it to or display them to my label. Currently the label text is hardcoded.

I created an array

```
const labels = [
   { label-one: 'text 1' },
   { label-one: 'text 2' }
]


<FormGroup>
    <FormControlLabel
      control={
        <Checkbox
          checked={checkOne}
          onClick={() => setCheckOne(!checkOne)}
          onChange={checkOne ? null : (event) => handleChange(event)}
          name="gilad"
        />
      }
      label="I would like to replace this text with either text 1 or text 2 thats stored in my array"
    />
```

Comment: You mean like `label={labels["label-one"]}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
  labels.map(label => (
    <FormControlLabel
      control={
        <Checkbox
          checked={checkOne}
          onClick={() => setCheckOne(!checkOne)}
          onChange={checkOne ? null : (event) => handleChange(event)}
          name="gilad"
        />
      }
      label={label["label-one"]}
    />
  ))
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do something like:

```
{
  labels.map(labelName => (
    <FormControlLabel
      control={
        <Checkbox
          checked={checkOne}
          onClick={() => setCheckOne(!checkOne)}
          onChange={checkOne ? null : (event) => handleChange(event)}
          name="gilad"
        />
      }
      label={labelName}
    />
  ))
}
```